# SaltStack gitfs issue

Tags: salt-stack

I'm learning saltstack using docker containers (bbinet/salt-master and bbinet/salt-minion), but can't get gitfs running. I'll need to run some containers later in production, so i'm trying to simply spin up a rabbitmq installation, but, however, Salt doesn't seem to see git remotes in my master config:

```
# /etc/salt/master (full, there's nothing more)
auto_accept: True
gitfs_provider: gitpython
fileserver_backend:
  - git
  - roots
gitfs_remotes:
  - git://github.com/saltstack-formulas/docker-formula.git

# state being applied (full, the AMQP container is written in pillar)
include:
  - docker.containers

# result of state.apply call:
amqp-minion-1:
    - Specified SLS docker.containers in saltenv base is not available on the salt master or through a configured fileserver
```

Output of `salt-run fileserver.file_list backend=git` is totally empty, so, as far as i can think, i'm doing something wrong specifying gitfs remotes. What could i do wrong and what  utilities should i use to debug this case?

update: the same behavior is observed using freshly-installed pygit2, i think there's just something i miss

update #2: it seems that config is completely ignored, salt-call --local config.get gitfs_remotes returns nothing, other options like auto_accept are not changing whatever is specified in config. Log tells me that config is read, however, that doesn't change a thing(even if consists only of `auto_accept: False` line).
salt-master version 2015.5.3

Comment: Any useful output in `/var/log/salt/master`? Also keep in mind that you usually need additional python packages for gitfs to work.

Comment: @helmbert no, nothing useful. When i've tried dulwich and tried `fileserver.file_list` command, salt explicitly mentioned that dulwich version is too low, however, gitpython is already installed

Answer (score 3):

I know this late, but hope it helps.

When going about debugging this, I think a quick indicator that you have it actually utilizing the config is to see if the auto_accept is actually working. Add some salt minions on the network, and point them to this salt master. See if they actually connect. Give it a minute if it doesn't immediately work. Assuming the networking is set up correctly and minions know where to find their master, do the following. Try a manual approach if this assumption isn't met.

Then from the master call `salt '*' salt-key -L`. You can also `tail /var/log/salt/master` to see any apparent failures to load the config. It will likely warn you if that is the case. Make sure the config is in /etc/salt/master before your start the process/service depending on how you are starting salt.

If your salt master is in a container you can also run the command
docker logs

Also considering including the rabbitmq salt formula in your master config like the following.

`gitfs_remotes:
 - git://github.com/saltstack-formulas/docker-formula.git
 - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/rabbitmq-formula`

I tried your salt command and received the following output:

`[]# salt-run fileserver.file_list backend=git
- FORMULA
- LICENSE
- README.rst
- pillar.example
- rabbitmq/config.sls
- rabbitmq/config_bindings.sls
- rabbitmq/config_exchange.sls
- rabbitmq/config_queue.sls
- rabbitmq/init.sls
- rabbitmq/install.sls
- rabbitmq/latest.sls
- rabbitmq/package-map.jinja
- rabbitmq/rabbit-management.sls`

Using a similar set up. I did not have to specify the gitfs_provider in order to get it to work. For some background I did a `yum install -y python-pip git` and then did a `pip install GitPython`.

It is also worth mentioning that gitpython is finicky based on the version of python the system has installed, so double check that as well.